# Grails GORM how to sort on hasMany where type is String

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am wondering how to set a default sort order where the hasMany is of type String, by example:

```
static hasMany = [possibleValues: String]

 static mapping = {
    possibleValues sort: '???', order: 'asc'
}
```

Normally you can set this on a field of the association, but here the association is not a Domain class.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a unidirectional association, so [default sort order isn't supported](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-4089). Apparently the sorting relies on having a join table handy.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, and as I can't have a join table to String then it looks like the only option is to create a new simple Domain class to achieve this...cheers